# How to download a webpage in every five minutes?

Tags: python, download, html, wget, web-crawler

I want to download a list of web pages. I know wget can do this. However downloading every URL in every five minutes and save them to a folder seems beyond the capability of wget.
Does anyone knows some tools either in java or python or Perl which accomplishes the task?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try using cron with wget.

Comment: @wuub: sounds like a good solution. Why not put it in an anwser so it can be accepted?

Comment: @Mark: because in my book this does not count as an answer, just a 0xDEADBEEF in the right direction :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write a bash script that uses wget and put it in your crontab to run every 5 minutes. (*/5 * * * *)

If you need to keep a history of all these web pages, set a variable at the beginning of your script with the current unixtime and append it to the output filenames.

Comment: Just curious: if the history part you described isn't needed, why whould you want to wrap the wget command in a (bash) script? You can also just call wget from cron, right?

Comment: since there's a series (group) of pages?

Comment: Erm... Yes, that makes sense. :)

Answer (score 7):

Sounds like you'd want to [use cron with wget](http://www.scrounge.org/linux/cron.html)

---

But if you're set on using python:

```
import time
import os

wget_command_string = "wget ..."

while true:
    os.system(wget_command_string)
    time.sleep(5*60)
```

Comment: Does python have a launchd interface?